# AVAudioPlayer noise when played simultaneously (few AVAudioPlayers created). only on iPhone 8/X

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, noise

I've encountered a weird bug.
I try to play a sound file, simultaneously. In order to achieve that i've created a manager that creates few instances of AVAudioPlayer, and then it plays the available one (the one that's not playing).

on iPhone 8/X, I hear lots of noise/clicks , specially at the end of the sound. on iPhone 6 it works fine. I guess it has something to do with device's speakers or the device ability to play stereo/mono, but it didn't make sense to me that there's no workaround for that.

Is anyone familiar with this problem and can suggest a solution ?

I can provide more information if needed..

Thanks!

Comment: I had similar issue with clicks in the end of audio. Mine was because of the audio file itself. If it ends (or you stop it) "in the middle of some sound" (can't remember the correct term for it) it would click. I got rid of it by adding ~500 ms of silence in the end of the file. It was also a behaviour specific to iPhone/iOS combinations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. Unfortunately it didn't help... I've encountered this issue only with iPhones 7 and up..

Comment: You could also check if you have your AVAudioSession properly configured, but if it works fine on other phones I guess you have already done it.

Comment: Yea it's not related to AVAudioSession...